# Django {% extend static "template.html" %} throwing TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: python, html, django

I have a template.html file full of some boiler plate html text.

Then in index.html I have:

```html
{% load static %}
{% extends static 'template.html' %}
```

In settings.py I have (relevent things):

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'notes.apps.NotesConfig', 
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

However, when I try to render index.html I get a
`TemplateSyntaxError at 'extends' takes one argument`.
When template.html was placed in the same directory as index.html and I used

```html
{% extends 'template.html' %}
```

everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you use {% extends %} in a template, it must be the first template tag in that template. Template inheritance won’t work, otherwise.

We'll that is according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance), so I am not sure you can load static.

The question is why do you wish to extend static? Move it to templates and then extend the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to add a reference to your static folder so that Django knows where to look for static files.
For that, you need to add the following lines of code in your `settings.py` file.
Assuming that you have a folder for static files in the base directory, the same place where the `manage.py` file lives. You just need to add the following lines to your `settings.py`.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
]
# Assuming the name of your static files folder is "staticfiles"
```